Repeater ACF WORDPRESS is not wordking
<?php

// Check rows exists.
if( have_rows('accordion') ):

    // Loop through rows.
    while( have_rows('accordion') ) : the_row();

        // Load sub field value.
        $sub_value1 = get_sub_field('accordion_title');
 $sub_value2 = get_sub_field('accordion_content');
        // Do something, but make sure you escape the value if outputting directly...

    // End loop.
    endwhile;

// No value.
else :
    // Do something...
endif;

?>

I wrote it correctly and tried everything but it still doesn't show up

ivdjjkbnkljsdnv              dljkvdkjdkjv dkj                                     dkjv dkj kdj kjd vkjndskjv nkdjv jkldvn kjdfv lkdfnlnclkv zx,c vm, ,mcx ,mdfkjbn dnv kn dfkjdn jknd kj ckjn dfcn dlnbk jfk kf kj



In what way is it not working?
